# Como actualizar los segundos en tiempo real?

Tags: php7

Amigos estoy atascado en un programa que estoy haciendo. He creado una función en PHP que me permite imprimir la fecha y la hora en una tabla html. Al momento de imprimir la hora yo quiero que los segundos se actualicen en tiempo real, para hacer esto posible hay que estar refrescando a cada rato el navegador y no encuentro una función que me ayude a hacer cambiantes los segundos.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Date php</title>
<style>
    .h{background:rgba(50,250,120,0.5);font-weight:bold;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php function Hora(){ ?>
    <table border='1'>
        
<!--como titulo de la tabla colocamos el dia-->
            <caption> <?php 
            date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
            $dia=date('D');
            switch($dia){
                case "Thu": $dia="Jueves";break;
                case "Fri": $dia="Viernes";break;
                case "Sat": $dia="Sabado";break;
                case "Sun": $dia="Domingo";break;
                case "Mon": $dia="Lunes";break;
                case "Tue": $dia="Martes";break;
                case "Wed": $dia="Miercoles";break;
                default: echo " ? "; }
                echo $dia;
            ?>
            </caption>
<!--encabezado-->
        <thead>
            <th>DIA</th>
            <th>MES</th>
            <th>AÑO</th>
            <th>HORA</th>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo date('d'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo date('M'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo date('Y'); ?></td>
                <td class="h"><?php echo date('H:i:s'); ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php }Hora(); ?>
```

Comment: 1) Con Javascript sin refrescar la página. 2) Con PHP, llamados ajax y un iframe (que es un poco overkill)

Comment: A reserva de conocer tu caso de uso, no necesitas ir a un servidor cada segundo a obtener el segundo actual, basta conque tengas una referencia inicial y uses el reloj del sistema. Para casos poco mas complejos consultar un servidor [NTP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) sería  suficiente.